# XSLT- Transforming a list of repeating elements with little structure into ordered list

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform output from a source of xml as shown.  My attempt is shown

Input:

```
 <products>
   <name>bananas</name>
  <price>3.55</price>
  <sku>1223-777-93222</sku>
  <name>pineapple</name>
   <price>1.25</price>
   <sku>013-144-9355</sku>
 </products>
```

Expected output:

```
    <orders>
    <order>
     <name>bananas</name>
     <price>3.55</price>
     <item-number>1223-777-93222</item-number>
     </order>
    <order>
     <name>pineapple</name>
     <price>1.25</price>
     <item-number>013-144-9355</item-number>
    </order>
    </orders>
```

XSLT:

```
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="name">
       <order>
         <name><xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="price">
       <price><xsl:value-of select="."/></price>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="sku">
        <item-number><xsl:value-of select="."/></price></item-number>
        </order>
       <xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        </orders>
      </xsl:otherwise>
```

However, I couldn't get it to work. It does not print what I expect. I would appreciate some help in transforming the output.

Please help, thank you

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected output?

Comment: This is what's expected:  <orders>
    <order>
     <name>bananas</name>
     <price>3.55</price>
     <item-number>1223-777-93222</item-number>
     </order>
    <order>
     <name>pineapple</name>
     <price>1.25</price>
     <item-number>013-144-9355</item-number>
    </order>
    </orders>

Comment: Your code shouldn't even load. XSL has to be well-formed XML and you can't close an orders tag within an xsl:otherwise tag. XSL has to use recursion rather than iterative or linear logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question XSLT 2.0, you can use [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) and `group-starting-with`...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <orders>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="name">
        <order>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </order>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </orders>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sku">
    <item-number>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </item-number>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Didn't notice you wanted to change the output of `sku`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is regular (i.e. each item is represented by exactly the same three elements, in the same order), you can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <orders>
        <xsl:for-each select="name">
            <order>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::price[1]"/>
                <item-number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::sku[1]"/>
                </item-number>
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```